# how to make user interface decision by self and better decision

Tags: design-patterns, user-interface, user-controls

hi i am very bad at user interface design and flow of program in terms of user places of widgets and buttons ,please suggest me how to take better user interface decision for this what can i do ?

regards

rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If the application you develop is a part of an existing system, try to follow the UI design and conventions of that system.
2. follow the conventions for the OS.
3. Use leveled UI.
4. Group UI controls by roles they have (like Copy/Cut/Paste in one group).
5. "Don't make me think" by Steve Krug might help you (it is about site design, but there are useful rules for desktop apps as well).

Answer (score 1):

Read the book [Don't make me think](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321344758) by *Steve Krug*

Answer (score 0):

Everybody can be better, just think what do you want the user to notice when he looks at the screen and how to make the flow of knowledge apparent to the user.

Also there are some conventions, like "OK\Cancel" buttons will be under all edit controls because the user should use them after going through all the fields.

Too many fields will make the user frustrated.

etc..

Answer (score 0):

I could not give you the exact answer but one book changed a lot of thought process for me "Don't Make me think" Steve Krugs. Read this book it will be of great help.

Also if you will follow jackob nielsen's useit.com\alertbox you will be benifited a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Look at control layouts in other apps (standard windows tools, well-known software and such) and try to do something similar. This method won't help you to create state of the art interfaces, but it'll eventually give you the idea about how things work. Make it look familiar for users and 99% of them will be happy.